# How Array in java can be homogeneous when we are allowed to create heterogeneous Array using Object class?

Tags: java, arrays

We say Array in Java is homogeneous. Still, we can store heterogeneous data by declaring the array as an Object as below: 
Object[] elements = new Object[10];

Then, how can we say Array is homogeneous? Can any one help me understand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Object[]` is still homogeneous!

Answer (score 5):

Array elements are homogeneous only at compile time; at run-time they may be heterogeneous.

An array is homogeneous only in terms of its elements' static, i.e. compile-time, type: all elements of the array are known to the compiler to have the same type.

As far as run-time type is concerned, however, any subtype of array's element type can be added to the array, opening a possibility for heterogeneous arrays at run-time.